# Azure Table Storage service 2.0 case sensitive filter

Tags: c#, azure, odata, azure-table-storage

How to perform case sensitive filter On Azure Table storage 2.0 ?

If i do this query
`TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("ShortUrl", QueryComparisons.Equal, "Abc");`

It will returns 2 records with shortUrl "Abc" and "ABC"
The generated query show like this

```
/devstoreaccount1/Articles?$filter=shortUrl%20eq%20%27Abc%27&timeout=90
```

There is a solution for version 1.7 shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703142/how-to-perform-a-case-sensitive-linq-query-in-azure) , but this is not applicable on version 2.0. I have checked  [DataService Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683669.aspx) and it is not mentioned there.

Since Table storage queries based on OData Protocol, why it behaves different when comparing string values. I am sure the Odata "eq" operator is supposed to be case sensitive.
Check [OData Api Explorer](http://services.odata.org/ODataAPIExplorer/ODataAPIExplorer.html) with this query

```
http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Products?$filter= Name eq 'Bread'
```

Then change it to bread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894031.aspx):

> All parts of the filter string are case-sensitive.

So I suggest that you try a real table storage, not the Development Storage. If you find this behavior on the real Storage service, please write here again, the team will be alerted!

Also please use the latest SDK/Tools (currently 2.0). If you find this behavior in development storage 2.0, update your question again, this might be a bug in the Development Storage.

But in any case, I suggest that you use real storage account when testing such "sensitive" features. I almost never use Development Storage account.

Comment: I have installed the latest SDK 2.0 today and found the filter is not case sensitive too. I will try real table storage later because my free account is ended. If you are sure from that in real Table i can accept this answer. May i have to do special code for development storage.

Comment: It works in real storage table. But in development storage it is case sensitive for partition key only. thanks